# Inflater Layout on button click

Tags: android, sqlite

i am using this code to play video :

```
void videoIntilize(View v, final Context ctx, final Activity act)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = act.openOrCreateDatabase("HadsKalme", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS videos (word VARCHAR,path TEXT,regdate VARCHAR);");

    final Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY regdate DESC", null);
    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
        //Nothing TODO
    } else {
        int i = 0;
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(act.getAssets(),
                "fonts/IRANSANS.TTF");
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            View ve = vi.inflate(R.layout.videotemplate, null, false);
            // fill in any details dynamically here
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) ve.findViewById(R.id.title);
            txt1.setText(" ویدئوی کلمه "+c.getString(0));
            TextView txt2 = (TextView) ve.findViewById(R.id.date);
            txt2.setText(" در تاریخ  "+c.getString(2));
            txt2.setTypeface(face);
            txt1.setTypeface(face);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) ve.findViewById(R.id.img);
            Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(c.getString(1),
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            ImageView player = (ImageView) ve.findViewById(R.id.playvideo);
            player.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(c.getString(1)));
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(c.getString(1)), "video/mp4");
                    act.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            // insert into main view
            ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.lnrelans);
            ve.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            insertPoint.addView(ve);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

in this code i am using Inflater Layout , when i clicking to play video this error appears :

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: ir.hiup.hadskalme, PID: 22609
                                                                   android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 9 requested, with a size of 9

how can solve this ? 
thanks for your time and help;

Comment: Does this happen when you click on all imageViews??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use cursor c from onClick method directly. 
in following code:

Replace this code

```
 player.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(c.getString(1)));
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(c.getString(1)), "video/mp4");
                act.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

with

```
 final String cursorUri = c.getString(1);
 player.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(cursorUri ));
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(cursorUri), "video/mp4");
                    act.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

As you are directly using cursor, when button is clicked, your cursor is pointing to location afterLast which is obviously not present hence it is giving exception.
Hope this answer is helpful.